# How to display multiple rows with the same ID

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Was hoping for some help on this matter. Title pretty much explains what I'm trying to do.

I'm using MySql Database to read the data off the UserID for the purchases they have made, however I've hit a wall because I'm stuck on how to read multiple rows with the same ID.

For exmaple

```
1, TestProduct
1, TestProduct2
```

^^^ As there are more rows populated with the same ID how can I read multiple rows?

This is what I'm currently doing and I'm aware this is not working as it's only taking/finding the first ID result it finds and using that one however, I haven't needed to populate multiple rows. So I'm at a loss

```
SearchUser_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@userid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Lbl_UserID.Text

Dim reader2 As MySqlDataReader

reader2 = SearchUser_COMMAND.ExecuteReader()


If reader2.Read() Then
  Lbl_Active.Text = reader2(3)
  Lbl_ProductName.Text = reader2(2)
  Lbl_ProductExpire.Text = reader2(6)
End If
```

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Thank very much in advance

Comment: Probably with a grid, not a label control.  Use `while reader2.Read()` to loop, or load the data into a DataTable and set the grid's DataSource to that DataTable.

Comment: @LarsTech Did think about using a datatable or grid, however would prefer to avoid using this method.. I'm trying to achieve the expire date of the purchase but can't do this without grabbing the UserID and Product Name. Obviously because there are multiple purchases each in different row I need to somehow read not one but get all of the data and then choose it according to the product they have. Is there a way to do this without the needing of a datatable?

Comment: Do you want to display the data on a label with multiple lines?

Comment: We don't know enough about your data, but you would have to do a `while reader2.read()` loop and when you find the record that fits your criteria, put that information into your labels.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, so I've got a few other labels that I can assign the data I need.. after I find it. Like ProductNames, ProductActive, ProductExpire etc.  If I tell the reader what Product Name it's looking for in the database and then when it finds it I can then read all the current values from that row? Is that possible? ^^ Will try that while loop in a bit and play around with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a class to hold your data, populate a List of those objects, then use some LINQ to iterate over them.

```vb
Private Class Data
    Public Property Active As Boolean
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Expire As DateTime
End Class
```

```vb
Dim items As New List(Of Data)

If reader2.HasRows Then
    While reader2.Read()
        items.Add(New Data() With {.Name = CStr(reader2(2)), .Active = CBool(reader2(3)), .Expire = CDate(reader2(6))})
    End While
    Lbl_Active.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items.Select(Function(i) i.Active))
    Lbl_ProductName.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items.Select(Function(i) i.Name))
    Lbl_ProductExpire.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items.Select(Function(i) i.Expire))
End If
' maybe clear labels otherwise
```

For a reader with three items, this should result in something like this

Lbl_Active:

> True
>
> True
>
> True

Lbl_ProductName:

> name1
>
> name2
>
> name3

Lbl_ProductExpire:

> date1
>
> date2
>
> date3

I took the liberty to assume the data types based on the names. You may have all strings in the database (you shouldn't) but then you should use strings.

Comment: Code above works lovely! I can now achieve what I wanted to do :)